# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision'

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, jupyter, microsoft-custom-vision

I am trying to use the microsoft azure custom vision service on a mac from Jupyter in VS Code

I have Python 3.8.3 installed.

I have done pip install azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision and confirmed it is there using pip show.

When I execute the command
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.prediction import CustomVisionPredictionClient

I get the error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision'

I have tried adding the location where the package is installed to $PATH but that does not fix the problem.

Any thoughts gratefully received! thx

Comment: Please check whether the python currently used by the VS Code terminal is the same as the one displayed in the lower left corner of the VS Code. ("python --version" or "pip --version")

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you always create and activate a [python virtual environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-local-development-environment?tabs=cmd#use-python-virtual-environments) to work with Jupyter notebooks, like an Anaconda environment, or any other environment in which you've installed the Jupyter package.

To select an environment, use the **Python: Select Interpreter** command from the Command Palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`). Once the appropriate environment is activated, you can create and open a Jupyter Notebook and connect to a remote Jupyter server for running code cells. Check [Working with Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) for more info.

This is true for application development in Python in general as well.

A virtual environment is a folder within a project that isolates a copy of a specific Python interpreter. Once you activate that environment (which Visual Studio Code does automatically), running `pip install` installs a library into that environment only.

When you then run your Python code, it runs in the environment's exact context with specific versions of every library. You can create a `requirements.txt` file for the libraries you need, then use `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Here is a snippet from a sample requirements.txt file:

```
azure-mgmt-core==1.2.0
azure-mgmt-network==16.0.0
azure-mgmt-resource==10.2.0
```

If you don't use a virtual environment, then Python runs in its **global** environment that is shared by any number of projects.

Refer to the [Azure SDK for Python Developer docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-local-development-environment?tabs=cmd) for more information on configuring your local Python dev environment for Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever U get: ModuleNotFoundError, the simple solution is to install the module using

```
pip install (module name)
```

For example, in your case try to run the following line:

```
!pip install azure
```

The ! is to run a command in a notebook.